# How to invite for facebook application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a Facebook application. We are using graph api in ASP.net with C# 2008. We have done the authentication process (Fb Oauth Authentication). We want Facebook app invite functionality. When a user allows our app, he must see invite window. I tried a lot but I didn't find any solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check it here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.inviteConnectUsers it is about connect user known by registered user as what we seen while using facebook to invite people

Comment: i never deploy facebook apps before while what i do previously is just found the API specialist for C# =D